# location manager given different geo coordinate

Tags: java, android

**Hello everybody I have a problem with LocationManager
I want to get my place position**

This my code:

```
protected LocationManager locationManager;

 @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10,
                10, this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText("My location = Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

            latitude  = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e("Latitude","disable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e("Latitude","enable");
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e("Latitude","status");
    }
```

Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The problem is when I tested in the emulator and on my phone both devices give different results
What can i do help please

Comment: Do you go to the emulator config to set the same location? Through the buttons that are next to the emulator

Comment: I use BlueStacks emulator when I go to the program through the emulator, the program gives such a coordinate Lat=41.30888894 Lon=69.30616819

but when I go through my phone the program gives such a coordinate 
Lat=41.299495697021484Lon=69.24007415771484